# Tkinter Text widget spacing

Tags: python, user-interface, fonts, tkinter

[image]

With the widget `Tkinter.Text` (especially when I use big size fonts) I have too much white space before the first line of text.
**How to reduce this font spacing with `Text` widget ?**

More generally, can we set negative spacing in order to have very short spacing between multiple lines ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried all of the available options? For example, the default for `pady` is probably 1, so setting that to 0 (zero) will free up one pixel. You might also want to double-check that the default value for `spacing1` is 0 (zero) -- it should be, but it's possible that it's not.

Other than that, I'm not sure there's much you can do. I think most of that space is unique to whatever font you use, so maybe you can choose a different font that requires less space between each line.

Comment: Thank you! I tried with `spacing1`, `spacing2`, etc.  in order to change spacings, but I cannot make it work with negative values (ie I also would like multiple lines to be closer from each other!)

Comment: I modified the original question about `negative spacing` (in order to have shorter spacing between multiple lines)

Answer (score 1):

There is a space for Unicode characters you personally do not know. Consider:
`Ť` goes above `T` in `ŤT`. The same as `g` goes under `o` in `go`

Comment: Thank you. But then would it be possible to have negative spacing (ie multiple lines would be closer to each other, and possibly overlapping) ?

Comment: You can always try to do some overlap hacking. Nothing I would enjoy personally :-D.